# Does this code contain a divide by zero error?

Tags: math, divide-by-zero, metatrader4, mql4

I have downloaded a <kbd>MetaTrader</kbd> **`MQL4`** language `.mq4` source-code file from [here](http://www.box.net/shared/cqls4666ll) and I think there is a divide by zero error contained in the file. The relevant section is:

```
                                   // Calculate sums for the least-squares method
n   = ( Taps - 1 ) / 2;

sx2 = ( 2*n + 1 ) / 3.0;

sx3 = n * ( n + 1 ) / 2.0;

sx4 = sx2 * ( 3*n*n + 3*n - 1 ) / 5.0;

sx5 = sx3 * ( 2*n*n + 2*n - 1) / 3.0;

sx6 = sx2 * ( 3*n*n*n*( n + 2 ) - 3*n + 1 ) / 7.0;

den = sx6 * sx4 / sx5 - sx5; // <---------------------------- a DIV!0 error here?
```

### This demo-code case:

Am I correct in my assumption that there is an error in the code,
*and **if** **so***,
perhaps someone could point out **what the correction should be**?

---

## General computation cases:

What is the industry best-practice / what practical software-design measures ought be used as a life-jacket protection for **`DIV!0`** incident(s)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A division by zero will occur if sx5 is zero. To find what would cause sx5 to be zero, solve sx5=0 for n.

```
0 = sx5
0 = sx3 * (2*n*n + 2*n - 1) / 3.0
0 = (n*(n + 1) / 2.0) * (2*n*n + 2*n - 1) / 3.0
...
0 = 2*n^4 + 4*n^3 + n^2 - n
```

One possible solution to that equation is n=0, so a division by zero error will occur if Taps is 1. I don't know if the equation has other solutions.

Update: Added math.

Comment: I don't see any division by n

Comment: @Belinda, sx5 is calculate from n

Answer (score 0):

```
den = sx6*sx4 / sx5 - sx5; // error here?
```

`sx5 - sx5` is presumably always equal to zero, so yes a divide by zero error will occur here.

Edit: Nevermind, this is incorrect

Comment: wouldnt the lack of parenthesis not allow `sx5 - sx5` to happen? it would do `sx6*sx4 / sx5` first, and then ` - sx5`

Comment: If Metatrader uses normal order of operations, sx5 - sx5 doesn't occur anywhere in the posted code.

Comment: Oh yeah, sorry I wasn't paying attention

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so, first the multiplication is done, sx6*sx4, then that is divided by sx5, then sx5 is subtracted from the final result.